# Truffle: VM Exception while invoking the SC-defined Ether transfer function

Tags: truffle, exceptions

I have two Smart contracts SC1 and SC2, I am sending ether from SC1 to SC2.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
contract SC1 {
    address owner;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function transferTo(uint amount, address payable dest ) public {
        require(tx.origin == owner);
        dest.transfer(amount);
    }
    function () external payable{
    }
}
```

==

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
interface SC1 {  
   function transferTo(uint amount, address payable to   ) external;
}
contract SC2{

    uint public  count;
    address owner;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function() external payable  { 
      count++; 
      if (count < 2 ) 
         TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(msg.sender.balance, address(this));
      
   }
}
```

truffle script

```
var assert = require('assert');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");


module.exports = async function(callback) {
  try {
     let arg1 = ""
     let arg2  = ""
     let  amount = '6'
     const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
     const acc2 = accounts[2];
     transferFuncName= "transferTo"
     const vic= artifacts.require("SC1");
     const att= artifacts.require("SC2");
     const vicobj = await vic.new();
     const attobj = await att.new();
     result1 = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:vicobj.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei(‘11’)})
    
     arg2 =  attobj.address
     arg1 = web3.utils.toWei(amount,"ether")
     result2 = await vicobj[transferFuncName](arg1, arg2, {from:accounts[0]})
    }
 catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  callback()
}
```

I am getting following error message:

```
Using network 'development'.

{ Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at module.exports (/home/zulfi/Truffle_programs/js_search_opcode_js/executingFunc.js:23:46)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  hijackedStack:
   'Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:1)\n    at /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:170:1\n    at /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:107:1\n
```

Somebody, please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem:
SC2 should be like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
interface SC1 {  
   function transferTo(uint amount, address payable to   ) external;
}
contract SC2{

    uint public  count;
    address owner;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function() external payable  { 
     
      
   }
}
```